# error while open shared libraries libmpi.so.12

Tags: mpi

I just installed mpi on my linux. Then I write a test program.

```
make
```

main.out is generated.

```
mpirun -n 4  ./main.out
```

Then error:.

```
error while open shared libraries libmpi.so.12
```

I find `libmpi.so.12` is just located at `/usr/local/lib`. I have included this directory in `makefile`. Why I cannot run `main.out`?

Comment: You should set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to contain `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: @HristoIliev, Yes. I found it works. But it here any way to permanently set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to contain `/usr/local/lib`? I mean every time I restart my computer I should set this environmental variable again.

Comment: That's what your shell configuration files (`.zshrc`, `.bashrc`, `.cshrc`, etc.) are for.

Comment: You can also link your application so that it always finds the library (for instance in gcc you may use -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$DIR) or you can also tune the configure dynamic linker run-time bindings (see man ldconfig).